# Weird results from solving an elliptic pde using FEM in Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am not sure where's the best place to ask this question but I am wondering if anyone has some insight on my problem.

I am trying to numerically solve the following PDE in divergence form:

$\nabla \cdot(c \nabla u) = 0$ subject to the boundary conditions:

$x \in [0,1] \times[0,2]\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, 
$u(0,x_2) = 0, u(1,x_2) = 1$ and  $u_{x_2}(x_1,0) = u_{x_2}(x_1,2) = 0$.

I'm trying out very simple functions $c(x_1,x_2)$.

Suppose that he coefficient has the form $c(x_1,x_2) = 2 + (8x_1^2 - 8x_1 + 1)(2x_2 - 1) +(2x_1 - 1)(8x_2^2 - 8x_2 + 1)$.

The graph of such a coefficient is as follows:
[image]

However, when I use Matlab's FEM solver even with the finest mesh, the solution looks like this:
[image]

I find it so strange that such a smooth coefficient $c(x_1,x_2)$ can yield such irregular of a solution.

But when I apply scaling parameters to my field $c(x_1,x_2)$, i.e. it now becomes

$c(x_1,x_2) = 2 + 0.2(8x_1^2 - 8x_1 + 1)(2x_2 - 1) + 0.1(2x_1 - 1)(8x_2^2 - 8x_2 + 1)$, the solution is well-behaved and respects the boundary conditions:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? I do not have the intuition behind this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diffusion coefficient $c$ is negative at places in your domain. For example $c(0,2)=-12$. The PDE is ill-posed when $c$ changes sign, since the equation is then not elliptic.

Your scaled diffusion coefficient is positive everywhere on your domain, so all is good.

Comment: Got it, Thanks Jeff! I did plot my coefficient but I realized that I did so on the wrong domain - I only considered the unit square instead hence the coefficient looked positive from there.

Do you have suggestions of coefficients $c$ which can be written as a linear combination of "basis functions"for which the resulting solution is a little bit more dramatic than the 3rd plot above?

Comment: If you allow $c$ to vanish, or get close to zero, in certain places, you will start to see interesting behavior, such as discontinuities in the solutions. Other than that, you may not see substantially different qualitative shapes to the graph of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Jeff! I will try that out.